# NoMethodError in MicropostsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

I cannot figure this out-
NoMethodError in MicropostsController#index

and

I have searched the web and cannot seem to make the right change.  I am doing Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and I am in ch 2 where we do microposts.
Here's index.html.erb

## Listing Microposts

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= micropost.content %></td>
        <td><%= micropost.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', micropost %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_micropost_path(micropost) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', micropost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Micropost', new_micropost_path %>
```

and

**Microposts Controller**

```
Class MicropostsController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

  def show

  end

  def new

  end

  def edit

  end

  def create

  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because *there is no microposts instance variable in index action*, in index action you should set @microposts like this:

```
def index
  @microposts = Micropost.all
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mandeep. It took away that error.  Thanks!